# Linux kernel module development buildroot

Tags: linux, kernel, c, buildroot, beagleboneblack

I have build a linux kernel for the beaglebone black using buildroot. Now I would like to develop a hello world linux kernel module application:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, cruel world\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

The problem is I still keep missing some header files. After finally gathering them all, I get an error that the code is not compilable (many errors, dont want to paste them all). What I was wondering is either I am really including the right files? At the moment I have:

```
/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-headers-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92/include
/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/uboot-2018.01/arch/x86/include
/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-headers-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92/arch/arm/include/generated
/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-headers-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92/arch/arm/include
/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92/include
```

Its a bit odd to me that the c include files and asm files are so scattered around within the directory.

My linux version:

```
# uname -a
Linux buildroot 4.9.59 #1 SMP Fri Oct 5 11:55:54 CEST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't give enough details on how you're building your Linux kernel module. Please follow the instructions at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt to learn how to build a kernel module.

Comment: Hi Thomas, you have already helped me with this problem over the buildroot mailing group at 20 December. In my case the problem was that I was including the linux headers instead of sources in the makefile.